# Importxml into Google Sheets automatically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to know how to import data using the Importxml function in Google spreadsheets.

https://www.tigeretf.com/front/products/product.do?ksdFund=KR7305080004&fundTypeCode=01000800

Above

```
<기준가격(원)>
```

I want to import data.

`importxml(I2,I3)`

I2 = `https://www.tigeretf.com/front/products/product.do?ksdFund=KR7305080004&fundTypeCode=01000800`

I3 = `//*[@id="container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/strong/text()`

Data is being loaded and cannot be refreshed.

I want the `<기준가격(원)>` data to be loaded automatically every time the sheet is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.tigeretf.com/front/products/product.do?ksdFund=KR7305080004&fundTypeCode=01000800", 
 "//strong[@class='price']"), "offset 1")
```

[image: 0]